# tick(grid) is overwriting with Y Axis in D3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, yaxis

I have created Js fiddle here [Please look](https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/8xvnmsfg/16/)

**Required like below X and Y  axis with black and grids are lighter**
[image]

**But getting below**
[image]
**Create YAxis scale and create ticks**

I set tickSizeInner(margin-width+100)  but its not work

```
    var yScaleTest = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    d3.min(this.materialGraphDataSource[0].materials, function (d) {
      return d3.min(d.materialStocks, function (d) {
        return d.item2;
      })
    }),
    d3.max(this.materialGraphDataSource[0].materials, function (d) {
      return d3.max(d.materialStocks, function (d) {
        return d.item2;
      })
    })])
  .range([height - margin, 0])
  .nice();

   /* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScaleTest)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickSizeInner(-height + margin)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%Y"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScaleTest)
 .ticks(14)
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickSizeInner(margin-width+200)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line")
      .attr("class", "axis_bar")
      .attr("stroke", "#E8E8E8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the first tick line, the one at the bottom, and remove it. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy2iii/bmL1x4j3/9/)

```
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .call(g => g.select('.tick:first-of-type line').remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line")
      .attr("class", "axis_bar")
      .attr("stroke", "#E8E8E8"))
```

Comment: @@Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen - No it change color on Y Axis. but here yAxis ticks are overwriting on X Axis.. Please can you look my attached JSFiddle here

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @@hugo-elhaj-lahsen. Its fixed thank you.. Added  .call(g => g.select('.tick:first-of-type line').remove()) and fixed. Thanks a lot